# test if display = none

Tags: jquery

This does not work, should it? Or can you stop the error if another line could do the same:

```
function doTheHighlightning(searchTerms) {
    // loop through input array of search terms
    myArray = searchTerms.split(" ");
    for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
    {
        // works. this line works if not out commented. Will highlight all words, also in the hidden elements
        //$('tbody').highlight(myArray[i]);

        // not working when trying to skip elements with display none...
        $('tbody').css('display') != 'none').highlight(myArray[i]);
    }

    // set background to yellow for highlighted words
    $(".highlight").css({ backgroundColor: "#FFFF88" });
}
```

I need to filter rows in a table and color some word. The data has become way to much for the coloring if many words are chosen. So I will try to limit the coloring by only going through the none hidden elements.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you want to get the visible `tbody` elements, you could do this:

```
$('tbody:visible').highlight(myArray[i]);
```

It looks similar to the answer that **Agent_9191** gave, but this one removes the space from the selector, which makes it selects the visible `tbody` elements instead of the visible descendants.

---

**EDIT:**

If you specifically wanted to use a test on the `display` CSS property of the `tbody` elements, you could do this:

```
$('tbody').filter(function() {
     return $(this).css('display') != 'none';
}).highlight(myArray[i]);
```

Comment: Hi. The tbody:visible does the trick very nicely. Can search a huge amount of data and only highlight the displayed text. Great.

Comment: @Tillebeck - Just so you understand, a 'space' in a selector is an important operator. It signifies that you are looking for a descendant. So `tbody:visible` looks for `tbody` elements that are `visible`, while `tbody :visible` looks for *descendants* of `tbody` that are `:visible`. Best of luck! :)

Answer (score 43):

Use like this:

```
if( $('#foo').is(':visible') ) {
    // it's visible, do something
}
else {
    // it's not visible so do something else
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Not best practice but i think this is best way to beginners.

Comment: This works great for slideToggle and IE8 because IE considers padding to be the height #justSayin

Comment: @tersakyan What is a best practice here?

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead to only select the visible elements under the `tbody`:

```
$('tbody :visible').highlight(myArray[i]);
```

Comment: For some reason it does not work. When removing the space between tbody and :visible (tbody:visible), then it does work. I can not tell if it should work (I may have some buggy software running, don't know). But thanks a lot for your answer. Sorry, but I marked patricks answer as right even though it was almost a clone of yours ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tbody').find('tr:visible').hightlight(myArray[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Agent_9191 and @partick mentioned you should use

```
$('tbody :visible').highlight(myArray[i]); // works for all children of tbody that are visible
```

or

```
$('tbody:visible').highlight(myArray[i]); // works for all visible tbodys
```

Additionally, since you seem to be applying a class to the highlighted words, instead of using jquery to alter the background for all matched highlights, just create a css rule with the background color you need and it gets applied directly once you assign the class.

```
.highlight { background-color: #FFFF88; }
```

Comment: Super. Thanks for the explanation. That may explain why only the latter one works (visible tbodys). And yep. CSS should go into the CSS file and not be defined in various js files. Both for performance but also so the design guys don't get frustrated :-) Will do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to test if `display` is equivalent to `none`:

```
if ($(element).css('display') === 'none' ){
    // do the stuff
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When posting code in your answer, it is helpful to explain how your code solves the OP's problem :)